# How to export image files into runnable JAR with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Title speaks for itself. I've made a clone of space invaders which uses several image assets. How do I tell eclipse to export the image files into the runnable JAR so they can be used by the program? I'm using eclipse europa.

Answer (score 2):

As Mr. Anderser pointed out, make sure to read them as resources when inside of a jar, not files.

This might help.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("images/imageFile.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Images inside jar files must be read as resources and not plain files.

You can create a new sourcefolder, e.g. named "images", and put your images in there.

Comment: Ok, I've made a new folder and put my images in it. When I ask eclipse to build the JAR and open the JAR with winrar, the folder doesn't get exported

Comment: Ensure that the source folder containing your images shows up in the workspace you currently are using in eclipse. You should be able to see the Project -> src -> Package -> Classes [inside the package with the classes, you should see a folder named "images".] Then when exporting, you want to select the classes and the folder to export.